# He activated/acted as a lawyer... (Instead of "worked")

Tags: verbs, synonyms

> He ***worked*** as a lawyer for an international corporation.

Could I rewrite it instead:

> He ***activated*** as a lawyer for an international corporation.

(Why? Simply for the reason of avoiding repetition. I used already ***work*** in a sentence above, in my paragraph.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To activate means to cause something to become active. You can't use that word in the suggested context.

If you are looking for a different way of saying "He worked as a lawyer for an international corporation.", you can say:

"He practiced law for an international corporation."

As for "He acted as a lawyer", that suggests that he is an actor that played the role of a lawyer in some film/play, or even worse - pretended to be a lawyer (i.e. falsely led others to believe he was an actual lawyer).

Comment: Thank you both! It helped me. I was confuse because I found in Google Books some examples of which meaning was not much obvious (to me).

Comment: `As for "He acted as a lawyer", that suggests that he is an actor that played the role of a lawyer in some film/play, or even worse - pretended to be a lawyer` It can also be used to indicate whether or not an actual lawyer is taking on that role in a particular action, or whether they're acting as a private citizen.

Comment: @nick012000 Good point, but I think such usage of "He acted as a lawyer" should appear within context that makes it clear that's the intended meaning.

Comment: @Eran, I forgot to ask, by saying that he *practiced law* for a business, does it imply that he *worked as an employee* in the legal department of that business, or rather he was an independent contractor, or associate? Because I need him to be a stable employee of that business. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @QOTSA I believe that since he practiced law for a business, this implies he worked for that  business.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use the word ***activated*** in that way. If by ***activated***, you mean it was his first job, you could say:

> His first job was as a lawyer for an international corporation.

Or you could simply say:

> He was a lawyer for an international corporation.

This is perfectly good, too:

> He became a lawyer for an international corporation.

Comment: What about **acted**?

Comment: That's not really great, because ***acted*** can mean ***pretended***. ***Practiced law*** that @Eran mentioned is a pretty good option. Or ***became a lawyer*** is fine, too.